# How to atomize complex structures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

This is a simpified version of a complex data strcture that I have:

```js
const todos = [
  {done: false, text: '...', tags: [{text: '...'}, {text: '...'}]}
]
```

To leverage the power of recoil, I have broken down the structure into various atom families, and I'm linking them through unique IDs:

```js
const tag = atomFamily({...});
const todo = atomFamily({...});
const todos = atom({...});

// The state looks something like this:
// todos = ['id1', 'id2'];
// todo('id1') =  {done: false, text: '...', tags: ['id1', 'id2']}
// tag('id1') =  {text: '...'}
```

But breaking the structure like this adds a lot of complexity to the code. For example, when I add a new `todo` to the list, I have to iterate over the list of `tags` and create tag atoms.

Similarly, when I remove a `todo` I have to iterate over all the internal `tag` atoms and remove them as well.
This gets more complex the deeper the nesting is.

Is there a best practice for atomizing a deeply nested structure like this?